# Сборка карты и скриптов в моём 2D движке, C++, SDL

Tags: скрипт, движок, c++, компиляция

Пишу свой движок(хотя даже не уверен, что это можно назвать движком), используя **SDL** и **C++**. Всю структуру взаимодействия частей движка беру из головы, точнее тщательно обдумав, используя клочок бумаги, реализую. Уже довольно многое реализовал на данный момент, сейчас возник вопрос следующего содержания: как компилировать скрипты, написанные на моём языке, используя именно трансляцию в С++, а потом тем же mingw компилировать и этот код?

Я не хочу исполнять оттранслированный код виртуальной машиной (это главное требование, из-за медленности исполнения сиего, и из-за принципа, с детства учили, что всё что можно написать, чтобы работало быстро и удобно, надо писать именно так). Как компилировать текст отдельного скрипта, без перекомпиляции всей программы? Можно ли каким-либо образом вставить в движок (в его скомпилированный файл, например) код или ссылку на скомпилированный код?(с **asm** работал, думаю разберусь, но это довольно сложный путь) Или в коде самого движка указать, к примеру, файл из которого читать имена скомпилированных файлов скриптов, которые нужно подгружать перед запуском(т.е. как их подгружать в виде кода)? Или какая-либо другая технология, которая позволит подключать скомпилированный код в уже скомпилированный файл.
Тот же вопрос относится и к картам. Возможно скрипты будут вшиты в карту, собственно у меня получится не большая разница между скриптами и картами.

В крайнем случае скорее буду рекомпилировать весь движок, чем использовать виртуальную машину (если конечно компиляция всего не будет слишком долгой).

Comment: Метка "скрипт" релевантна, зачем ее удалять?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Я думаю, Вам нужны обычные dll. Накладные расходы будут достаточно минимальными. Подгружать-выгружать можно стандартными функциями (LoadLibrary). Нужно только будет сделать соглашение об наименовании функций.

Comment: Каждый скрипт компилировать в отдельную dll, или все в одну?
Можете дать ссылку на литературу, максимально близкую к этой теме?
Спасибо за идею, совсем про них забыл, к тому же мало с ними работал.

Comment: я думаю, нужно группировать скрипты и компилировать по dll. Точно не нужно все валить в одну кучу (это будет очень долго компилироваться), но и не стоит разбивать на сотни - это все ещё нужно будет загрузить.
Ссылка - [офф.сайт](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/sampleDLL).

Comment: Спасибо большое, буду разбираться!

Comment: @Vincento Law Так Quake II устроен. Соответственно, чтение его исходников может вам быть полезным.